# Disputed Triage audit - fixed Wikipedia article

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Take a look at the Triage queue audit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15840288)

Well, the question itself is fine.

However, I noticed the comment that the Wikipedia article is already fixed. This means that the question is invalid.

Thus, I have flagged with the follow off-topic reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

I doubt that asking with such wrong reference makes sense. The only answer doesn't seems satisfying (not accepted), too.

**Are such questions acceptable?** It seems to have a lot of upvotes, but obviously it doesn't contains useful information.

(By the way, I was lucky enough to not get banned by this, but I guess the next one will kill me again)

Comment: This is why, boys and girls, you shouldn't use Wikipedia as your primary source.

Comment: @gnat I'm not focusing on the audit failure; I'm wondering how this post should be treated.

Comment: the post is not OK, and it most definitely is a poor audit. Duplicate explains how it happens that such posts make it into audits (in brief, brainless automated system blindly follows handful of random upvotes and simple formatting check to decide that it's good enough for audit)